# Setting coordinate system for image in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, exogeography

I am a beginner with ArcMap. I have a problem with setting coordinate system for my image. I am using an add-in which
creates shapefiles .shp (craters, area), grids, plots and etc. However I get errors (like the ones attached). Basically how do I
correctly set the coordinates so that ArcMap correctly interprets position of the shapefile on the map?

I know the number of columns and rows i.e. pixels, of my image and I know the resolution of my image (0.82m/px).
Link: http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/view_lroc/LRO-L-LROC-3-CDR-V1.0/M1142616950LC   (CDR PTIF (multi-resolution, lossy compression))

EDIT: I am attaching the [tool](http://hrscview.fu-berlin.de/mex4/software/cratertools/CraterTools(v2.1).zip) which creates the shapefiles. In summary: with this tool one can measure the diameter and x,y of selected craters (circle shapes) and the area (polygons) in km^2 of the counting zone.

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Is that craters on the moon (or another planet)? To set a spatial reference right click on the raster in ArcCatalog, select properties, scroll down to where it says spatial reference and hit 'define', you will be given a list to pick from... your tool wants a projected coordinate system so find one in there.

Comment: Your linked image looks like it is extra-terrestrial so while the steps to define its coordinate system are easy, deciding what coordinate system to use may be much harder.  In any event including the location of your data by using the **edit** button beneath it would seem highly relevant.  Also, does one or other of your image and shapefile already have a coordinate system?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson  -1 for suggesting that the OP directly define a projected CRS. The image metadata in the link clearly shows lat/lon and that it's the earth's moon (well, a moon, but other planet's moons have names so...!).

Comment: @mkennedy, I missed the *moon* part in the metadata on first reading, I was commenting on the appearance which could just as easily be seabed. The instructions are for if you know what it is but it isn't set, expecting it to be one of the options in the list... this is the first time I've encountered anything not on the earth and I'm a little out of my depth (or should that be height)?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I tried to go to spatial reference in ArcCatalog but I couldn't change the value there. Says <undefined> and can't select it

Comment: @PolyGeo well i set "GCS_Moon_2000" for my shapefiles but the problem persists and I get the same errors (screenshots)

Comment: What format is it in? Is the dataset/folder/drive read only or do you lack permission to write to the device/folder?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson its TIFF. yes it is read only but i have full permissions of the folder.

Comment: Change it to not read-only, the spatial reference is carried by a tag inside the GeoTiff file so it needs to be written to (as well as an aux file for compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

According to the metadata on the data's source webpage, there are latitude and longitude values for the image which means you need to georeference it (if it isn't already) using those values.

For the longitude values, I would switch to a +/-180 range, rather than a 0 to 360 range. So for the upper left longitude of 332.26, I would use -27.74 instead.

Once the raster is georeferenced (or if it already is), set the coordinate system via the data's property page in ArcCatalog or the Define Projection tool and set it to "Moon 2000", which is in the geographic coordinate systems, Solar System folder.

Because the add-in you want to use wants a projected coordinate reference system instead, you'll have to now use the Project Raster tool to create a new raster that's using a projected coordinate reference system. ArcGIS doesn't have any predefined, so you'll need to create a new one, based on the GCS Moon 2000. The image is relatively small, so various projections could be used.

Comment: There aren't many extra terrestrial coordinate systems so the user is going to have to 'roll their own', which is kind of advanced even for the ArcGis veteran. Perhaps the tool doesn't do anything with projections but just wants it to be projected (I can't say for sure, but it's a possiblity) perhaps if the user defined the data to (for example) WGS84/UTM Zone 12 North and then modified the spatial reference of the results to what it should be... this would only work though if the tool doesn't project the data at any stage.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes I think the tool wants the shapes to be projected. I have attached the addin itself, if you can please take a look.

Comment: That's compiled, do you have the source code available? It seems from the docs it's specifically for extra terrestrial crater investigation.. not something that I've worked with before. I would think that the need for projected data has to do with getting correct results from IArea.area.

Comment: The [source page for the software](http://hrscview.fu-berlin.de/software.html) describes it as "for map-projection-independent crater size-frequency determinations" which certainly makes me wonder why it needs to be projected. It further says the software is based on/described in [a paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032063310000887), the abstract of which may give some guidance on how it generally works. I also note the source image is one of a stereo pair. Question is tagged as 10.3, plugin is for 10.x - wonder if .3 broke something since it's relatively new.

Answer (score 2):

So I got it to work finally. The image was read only so I couldn't define spatial reference.
Having fixed that the only work to be done with the available image was to define its coordinates and projection. So had to create a custom coordinate system with GCS Moon 2000 and Mercator projection (sphere). And voila no need for tedious georeference or Project Raster tool.